# Check XML before creating XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I load xml by Xdocument:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();
                document = XDocument.Load(filepath);
                var list = document.Element("Items").Elements("Item").Select(Items.FromXElement).ToList();
```

If Xml file did not contain element "Item" or "Items" programm occurs a NullReference Exception.
How i can check my xml file on the content of elements, before this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

**Option 1: XPath**

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var list = document.XPathSelectElements("/Items/Item").Select(Items.FromXElement).ToList();
```

**Option 2: Helper method**

```
static class XExtensions
{
    public static XElement ElementOrEmpty(this XContainer container, XName name)
    {
        return container.Element(name) ?? new XElement(name);
    }
}

var list = document.ElementOrEmpty("Items").Elements("Item").Select(Items.FromXElement).ToList();
```

**Option 3: [Validate your XML document against a schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using XPath.  Run this through LinqPad:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
"<Items>" +
  "<Item>" +
  "</Item>" +
"</Items>");

var items = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements(@"//Items/Item");

items.Dump();
```

If no `Items` exist, an empty IEnumerable will be returned.